# How can I make Neovim's 'e' map make an extra position?

Tags: vim, text-editor, neovim

I am trying to remap 'e' keybind with `:nnoremap e mynewcommand`, but I am a bit lost about how to make the current "end of word" finish one extra position.

For example, right now if I have `word1 Xword2 word3` (X being the current position), it ends here: `word1 wordX word3`.

Is there a way to remap it so that it ends on end of word + 1 position? Like this: `word1 word2X word3`

Thanks!

Edit1: For some weird reason, when doing the remap: `:nnoremap <S-l> e` , works like a charm - but, the `:nnoremap <S-j> b`  doesn't work at. Does anyone have any idea?

Edit2: As requested, here is my vim.init:

```
:nnoremap t r
:nnoremap <SPACE> <INSERT>
:vnoremap i <UP>
:vnoremap <SPACE> <INSERT>
:nnoremap i <UP>
:nnoremap k <DOWN>
:nnoremap j h
:nnoremap <S-l> e 
:nnoremap <S-j> b 
:nnoremap a <S-A>
:nnoremap vv <S-V>
:vnoremap k <DOWN>
:vnoremap j <LEFT>
:nnoremap dw daw
:inoremap jh <Esc>

" Settings.

set nocompatible
set showmatch
set ignorecase
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent
set number 
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set ttyfast

" Vim-plug (Plugin Manager)

call plug#begin()
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'}
call plug#end()
```

Comment: can you share the code lua or vimscript?

Comment: Of course, I have posted it now.

Comment: that is probably a horrible idea, there are already movements to that position. Use `f<space>` to jump to the next whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: Vim (and Neovim) doesn't have "maps" so what you are doing are not "remaps", they are "mappings" (or "maps", if you really want).

**Second**: as someone already pointed out, `f<Space>` already covers your need so you probably shouldn't spend so much energy on this.

**Third**: `<S-l>` and `<S-j>` are convoluted and unnecessary ways to say `L` and `J`. Keep your config simple.

**Fourth**: `:help J` and `:help L` are two very useful commands in their own right so you should think hard about the relative benefits of overriding them. Especially for something as trivial as this.

**Fifth**: The   in `nnoremap <key> e`  is not very readable and is likely to disappear after some hasty formatting. You should consider these alternatives notations:

```
nnoremap <key> e<Space>
nnoremap <key> el
nnoremap <key> e<Right>
```

or maybe even:

```
nnoremap <key> f<Space>
```

**Sixth**: The way you explained your situation is not very clear:

```
word1 Xword2 word3
word1 wordX word3
```

Where did the `2` go? Which character was the cursor on, exactly? Could you rewrite it in a more explicit way? Something like:

Current behaviour:

```
word1 word2 word3
     ^               " position of the cursor before e
          ^          " position of the cursor after e
```

Desired behaviour:

```
word1 word2 word3
     ^               " position of the cursor before <key>
           ^         " position of the cursor after <key>
```

**Seventh**: I can, sort of, understand the desire for `nnoremap L e<Space>` because wanting the cursor to land right after the current word seems like a reasonable thing to want. You may want to put something, there, or insert a bracket, or whatever. But I fail to imagine a scenario common enough to justify `nnoremap J b<Space>`. What, exactly are you trying to do with that mapping? What problem are you trying to solve? And, more importantly, what does "doesn't work" mean?

Are you trying to mirror your `L` mapping by landing the cursor *before* the word? Since `<Space>` moves the cursor to the right, then `b<Space>` is obviously not going to work but the following might:

```
nnoremap <key> b<Left>
nnoremap <key> bh
nnoremap <key> b<BS>
```

or maybe even:

```
nnoremap <key> F<Space>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to be able to navigate through the text while jumping words, both forwards and backwards, it uses to be pretty comfortable to me, that is why I am trying to set up the backwards keymap too.